# Kick Start - 18 - Round G - Product Triplets - Time_Limit_Exceeded

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting Time_Limit_Exceeded error on kick start 2018 Round G Product Triplets problem : Please help me

```
import itertools
T=int(input())
for t in range(1,T+1):
    N = int(input())
    A = list(map(int,input().split()))
    cnt = 0
    strings = list(itertools.combinations(A, 3))
    for i,j,k in strings:
        if (i==j*k) or (j==i*k) or (k==i*j):
            cnt += 1
    print("Case #{}: {}".format(t, cnt))
```

Comment: I think those kind of challenges aren't supposed to be solved by bruteforce. It looks like knapsack problem or similar. You can save time by not forcing the combinations to a list, though.

Comment: `strings = list(itertools.combinations(A, 3))` => `strings = itertools.combinations(A, 3)` is probably faster

Comment: you are correct @Jean-FrançoisFabre, but again it's giving TLE for large data set :(

Comment: I think I have to change algorithm Jean-FrançoisFabre

Comment: yes. The current one is bruteforce. AFAIR the idea is to create groups of products then sort them and use bisection to match the third value.

Comment: Hmmmm interesting man, I haven't think like that (I am at initial stage of solving problems). Thanks man that will work actually.

Comment: start with small data set & bruteforce to create a correct reference Then create the algorithm on the same small dataset to validate it against the bruteforce results. Then use the smart algorithm with bigger values.